# Get column name & table name from value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually I have a new client & their Database has no standard naming conventions & the application is in classic asp.I have a form in which a form there are many values in the different textboxes, it it very difficult to trace the value come from which table.& also there is no erd.

I need a query from which I can get the table name with column name by giving Value.

Let's suppose I have a value having label name abc#= '**6599912268**'

& the new project has no ERD no standard of naming conventions... I need a fast way to know the abc# ='**6599912268**' is taking from which table & which column name.... like this the UI has many values which is time taken to trace manually

Is there any way to trace it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. There is no way to trace table/column it comes from by mere inspection of the value.
I suggest the following.
Find out what type of db your product is using. Where it is situatede, do you have access to it.
If you have access to the database, get to know the db structure. What each table is meant to store, the relationships etc. Speak to the db administrator or the business analayst to increase your knowledge on the product domain. 
Once you have the db structure, try and compare the table to the page. Eg. The user details will most like be stored in a db table named 'Users' or 'Membership' Catch my drift?

Then have a look at the web sites source code. Look at the specific page you are at. Is the sql code embedded in the source code (asp page) or does it call a COM server or something similar? If you are "lucky" (and I say lucky for on the purpose of your problem that you are having) you fill find the sql code in the asp page.
If it calls a COM object or something similar, then you will have to dig up the source code for that, and that is most likely where you sql will reside.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, you have to use a stored procedure to loop over all the tables in the database and search for the value, and it will probably take a while.

There's a stored procedure and examples here: [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2). You'll see there are stored procedures for finding dates, strings, numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, and If you search the column with the value, there is a possible chance that you get multiple columns with the same value, so how would you differentiate them and the same case is for the table.